# How to use networkx graphs as input for sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, networkx, graph-theory

I want to apply sklearn graph clustering algorithms but they don't accept input from networkx in .gexf format. What kind of library/transformations do I need to turn my .gexf graphs suitable for sklearn?

Comment: Which clustering algorithm do you want to apply? networkx has some clustering algorithms like k-nearest neighbors implemented https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/algorithms.html

Comment: I want to use Affinity Propagation and Spectral Clustering. Not the clustering algorithms included in the networkx library

Comment: @Mnemosyne have you looked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258657/spectral-clustering-a-graph-in-python ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cluster algorithms accept either distance matrices, affinity matrices, or feature matrices. For example, kmeans would accept a feature matrix (say X of n points of m dimensions) and apply the Euclidean distance metric, while affinity propagation accepts an affinity matrix (i.e. a square matrix D of nxn dimensions) or a feature matrix (depending on the *affinity* parameter).

If you want to apply a sklearn (or just non-graph) cluster algorithm, you can [extract adjacency matrices](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/convert.html) from networkx graphs.

```py
A = nx.to_scipy_sparse_matrix(G)
```

I guess you should make sure, your diagonal is 1; do `numpy.fill_diagonal(D, 1)` if not.

This then leaves only applying the clustering algorithm:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import AffinityPropagation


ap = AffinityPropagation(affinity='precomputed').fit(A)
print(ap.labels_)
```

You can also convert your adjacency matrix to a distance matrix if you want to apply other algorithms or even project your adjacency/distance matrix to a feature matrix.

To go through all of this would go too far, however, as for getting the distance matrix, if you have binary edges, you can do `D = 1 - A`; if you have weighted edges you could `D = A.max() - A`.