# SpectralClustering vs. spectral_clustering in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I noticed that there are two different functions for spectral clustering in sklearn.cluster library: [SpectralClustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html) and [spectral_clustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.spectral_clustering.html). Although they differ in some details, both do spectral clustering and most of their parameters overlap. I am confused about why there are two methods so similar in sklearn?

Some differences I noticed:

- In SpectralClustering, parameter `affinity` takes both string and array; its default value is `'rbf'`; in spectral_clustering it can only be a matrix
- SpectralClustering() works like a constructor. It doesn't return anything but has two attributes `affinity_matrix_`(which you can access after calling .fit()) and `labels_`.  spectral_clustering is a method that only returns the labels.

Using SpectralClustering:

```
cluster=SpectralClustering().fit(X)
cluster.labels_
```

Using spectral_clustering:

```
labels=spectral_clustering(affinity_matrix)
```

Despite these apparent differences, I'm wondering whether these two methods differ in fundamental aspects. Otherwise why are there two methods that accomplish basically the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the source code?

I'd expect that `SpectralClustering` is an object oriented wrapper for the imperative method `spectral_clustering`.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of looking at the source code. You are absolutely right. `SpectralClustering` basically computes the affinity matrix by itself and then calls `spectral_clustering(Affinity_Matrix)`.